# Union of two sets,manipulating arrays Java

Tags: java, arrays, set-union

Idea is to calculate union of two collection sets,at the begining of the program,user will be asked to enter the length of desired sets,afterwards he will be prompted to assign the elements in sets,and the final idea is to calculate Union.
I have reached the very end and after compiling my program only elements of the first set are printed,I really don't know why.

**So my question is how can I calculate the sets union,following the idea I started.**

**MY OUTPUT:**

> Desired array lengths: 
>   3
>   3
>   First set elements: 
>   1
>   2
>   3
>   Second set elements: 
>   4
>   5
>   6
>   UNION of our sets: 
>   1.002.003

```
public class Union{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Desired array lengths: ");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Infinite loop for reading input,if negative number entered break the loop!

    while (true) {
        int n1 = scan.nextInt();
        int n2 = scan.nextInt();
        if (n1 < 0 || n2 < 0)
            break;

        // Assigning elements to the first set.
        double[] s1 = new double[n1];
        System.out.println("First set elements: ");
        //We enter elements as long as the number of the elements added is less than the length of an array we assigned.
        for (int i = 0; i < n1; s1[i++] = scan.nextInt());

            if (n1 == 0)
            System.out.println();//If we do not enter any element go to new line

        //Assigning elements to the second set.
        double[] s2 = new double[n2];
        System.out.println("Second set elements: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < n2; s2[i++] = scan.nextInt());

        if (n2 == 0)
            System.out.println();//Same as before.

        // Calculating union

        double[] s3 = new double[n1 + n2];//We reserve memory space for the s3 array with the size equal to both n1 and n2 arrays.
        int n3 = 0; // Variable used to save number of elements,after reaching the end of the loop n3 WILL HAVE THE SIZE OF N1.
        while (n3 < n1) 
            s3[n3] = s1[n3++];
        for (int j = 0; j < n2; j++) {  //HERE WE ARE CHECKING IF THE ELEMENTS FROM N2 SET ARE PRESENT IN THE N1 
            int i = 0;
            while (i < n1 && s2[j] == s1[i])
                i++;
            if (i == n1)
                s3[n3++] = s2[j];
        }

        double[] pom = new double[n3];
        for (int i = 0; i < n3; pom[i] = s3[i++]);

        s3 = pom;
        pom = null;

        System.out.println("UNION of our sets: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < n3; System.out.printf("%.2f", s3[i++]))
            ;
        System.out.print("\n\n");
    }

}
```

Comment: feel free for any queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake lies in the code where you are checking which elements of `set` `s2`, you need to put in `set` `s3`.

Basically you need to check whether an element of `set` `s2` is present in `set` `s1`.

So change following code:

```
for (int j = 0; j < n2; j++) {  
       int i = 0;
       while (i < n1 && s2[j] == s1[i])
         i++;
       if (i == n1)
         s3[n3++] = s2[j];
}
```

to this code:

```
for (int j = 0; j < n2; j++) {  
       int i = 0;
       while (i < n1 && s2[j] != s1[i])
         i++;
       if (i == n1)
         s3[n3++] = s2[j];
}
```

The loop `while (i < n1 && s2[j] != s1[i])` will terminate with `i = n1`, only when none of the elements in `set` `s1`, matches with element `s2[j]` and this is the element which we want in the `UNION` of 2 sets.

Comment: On the ball!
Thanks Sumeet,I overlooked this condition.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use the [Java Collections Framework](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/)? The [Set interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html) can do this very easily.

```
Set<Double> union = new HashSet<>();
for (double e : s1)
    union.add(e);
for (double e : s2)
    union.add(e);
System.out.println(union);
```

If you cannot use the collections framework and have to roll your own then you might consider rolling your own binary tree or heap.

Comment: I can't.I mean I can,but this was not the idea.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the following block:

```
while (i < n1 && s2[j] == s1[i])
    i++;
if (i == n1)
```

It's trying to compare the elements of two arrays with similar indices, e.g. if first element of `s1` and `s2` are not equal, control will break out of `while` loop and hence, `i` will never be `n1`, resulting in element at index `j` of s2 bein skipped.

As far as calculation of union is concerned, you can easily do it with `Set` in Java, e.g.:

```
Set<Double> elements = new LinkedHashSet<>();
for(double number : s1){
    elements.add(number);
}
for(double number : s2){
    elements.add(number);
}
double[] union = new double[elements.size()];
int i = 0;
Iterator<Double> iterator = elements.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()){
    union[i++] = iterator.next();
}
```